# ActionBarSherlock 4.4: Activity icon resource not correct

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the newest ActionBarSherlock release (4.4) and many of my Android 2 users experience a fatal crash while the sherlock library tries to load the activity icon.

I tried cleaning the project but the bug keeps appearing (I suspect the generated R file for the library is incorrect?). I found some topics covering this crash but no working solutions.

My project exists out of the ActionBarSherlock library which is used by another library project containing some Activities. A few other Android projects use the library project with the Activities in it. I don't think this could be the problem, could it?

Important thing to notice is that the app works fine on a emulator running Android 2.x. I'm also using proguard.

Could the crash have something to do with the `loadLogoFromManifest` method?

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/ResourcesCompat.java#L112

### Devices and Android versions affected so far

- Optimus L3 (e0)
- Galaxy Pocket (GT-S5300)
- Galaxy Y (GT-S5360)

Android 2.3.3 - 2.3.7

### Proguard

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
-keepattributes *Annotation*


-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockDialogFragment

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}


-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

### Stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packagehere/activityhere}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1010)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:902)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:836)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
at someactivity.onCreate(BibleMain.java:128)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
... 24 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File from drawable resource ID #0x7f020091
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.(ActionBarView.java:191)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
... 29 more
```